# debugger exception thrown on start program

Tags: delphi

Project *.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message
 `access violation at 0x005d9e17:read of adddress 0x00000008`.

About My program:
In form.formcreate(), do some initializaiton; then start a thread, in which init the columns of a listview:

```
ListView.Columns.Add.Caption := 'Path';
```

Just this clause throw the exception.   How to debug this problem?

And the program does not throw the exception every time. I run 10 times, only 5 times exceptions threw.

Stack:

```
:005d7e17 TListColumn.DoChange + $F    
:005d7f73 TListColumn.SetCaption + $23    
:004ccc74 ThreadProc + $4C    
:0040947a ThreadWrapper + $2A    
:76cf919f KERNEL32.BaseThreadInitThunk + 0xe    
:7732a8cb ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x84    
:7732a8a1 ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x5a
```

Comment: Start a fresh, new application, then use File->New->Other->Delphi Files->Thread Unit to generate a shell for a new thread. Now read the **very large comment block** at the top of that new unit, that clearly says you cannot access VCL controls from anything other than the main thread. Then search here for [delphi] thread and read the same information from the hundred other questions relating to trying to update VCL controls from a thread tor read again and again how you cannot access VCL controls from other than the main thread. Then repeat to yourself: No VCL controls except in main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly you are attempting to read a field or call a method on an object reference that is `nil`.

Typically you would tackle this by using the debugger to work out which reference is `nil` and then you should be able to determine how to resolve the problem.

You should be aware that you must not access VCL components from a thread other than the main thread. My guess is that this in fact is the reason for the access violation.

Use the `Synchronize` or `Queue` methods of the `TThread` class to invoke code on the main thread. However, as a general principle, threads should not be performing UI work. I wonder if you should contemplate a different design.

Comment: Thans David, I know your meaning. But I want to config some of the UI message in dababase.


So I use a thread to dynamically reload the columns info from mysql. 


The goodness is if someday, someone want to show a new column info, I needn't republish UI exe, only let the administrator to modify database.

Comment: You have to obey the rules. No VCL code away from main thread.

Comment: @coo I dont understand why have you moved such code into spereate thread in the first place. I mean in order for your application to work correctly you need to configure your GUI first so that it can show the data from the database corectly (have all the neccessary columns). Right? That means that cofiguring of GUI should happen before any data is read from the database. Right? But you have moved this code into seperate thread to try to do this in parallel. Why?

Comment: @coo: It doesn't matter what you "want". You **cannot** access VCL controls from a thread without using `Synchronize` or `Queue`. It's not a matter of your wants; it's the way the VCL (and WIndows) work.

Comment: @SilverWarior  I can give a cause from an example. While designing a listview to show data of mysql table, each table have different number of columns. So at design time, you don't know how many columns you need. So I think you should consider a thread to add columns after get data from database.

Comment: "I think you should consider a thread": Why do you think you need a separate thread to do this?

Comment: Use a thread. Don't use a thread. Up to you. But do the GUI work in the main thread.

Comment: @coo I understand your intended design where you get the number of columns at runtime after reading your database record. But I don't understand the need to use seperate thread to update your ListView number of columns acordingly. Now if you are doing all of your database access in seperate thread in order to ovid blocking of GUI due to long responce times from database that I can understand. But in such case you still need to make sure that the code which is directly afecting the VCL part of your application is still executed in main thread as other have already sad.